# Associated Lie algebras of p-groups of maximal class

Tags: lie-algebras, p-groups

I was reading a paper the other day on Lie algebras of maximal class and they keep saying that some results are taken from p-groups theory.

So my question is how do you get the associated Lie algebra of a p-group?
I assume that we get Lie algebras over a finite field, but still how do we get the bracket from the group multiplication? Is it just $[x,y]=xy$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can associate to a group $G$ a Lie ring $L(G)$ via the lower central series $G_i$, inductively defined by $G_1=G$ and $G_i=[G,G_{i-1}]$. The associated graded abelian group
$$
gr(G) = \bigoplus_{n>1} G_n/G_{n+1}
$$
has the structure of a graded Lie algebra
over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers, the bracket operation in $gr(G)$ being induced by the commutator operation in $G$, e.g., by
$$
[xG_i,yG_j] = [x,y]G_{i+j}.
$$

We can specialise this to finite $p$-groups, replacing $G_{i+1}=[G,G_i]$ by $G_{i+1}=[G,G_i]G_i^p$, obtaining a Lie algebra $L(G)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (because every factor group has exponent $p$).

Reference: [Finite $p$-groups in representation theory](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/FINITE-p-GROUPS-IN-REPRESENTATION-THEORY-Mazza/9224ec039e6dd75881508daa1b9c12f550e437f2), section $3$, Lazard correspondence.

Comment: No, you need to consider $G_{i+1}=[G,G_i]G_i^p$ instead of $[G,G_i]$. With the bare lower central series of a $p$-group $G$, you usually only get a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k$ (e.g., if $G$ is itself $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I have corrected it, thank you.

Comment: The link is broken. [This one](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/FINITE-p-GROUPS-IN-REPRESENTATION-THEORY-Mazza/9224ec039e6dd75881508daa1b9c12f550e437f2) works at the moment.